# how to solve java.net.BindEception on Startup IntelliJ

Tags: java, web-services, intellij-idea

This appear after startup idea.sh,

```
java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:127)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:554)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1258)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:512)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:497)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:980)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:250)
        at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:363)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:418)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:449)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm using slackware 14.2,  and intellij-idea community edition without JDK. I have others IDEs but those startup without problems.
My JDK version is JDK 8.

Comment: Google for "Cannot assign requested address", the issue doesn't seem to be IDE specific, your system fails to create network socket to listen for connections for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a system level issue & not IDE specific. You can look more details [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/02/fixing-javanetbindexception-cannot-assign-requested-address-JVMbind.html) under the ***second part*** (after red colored text).

The possible issue is your computer is unable to resolve an [IP address to host name mapping](http://javarevisited.blogspot.sg/2011/09/find-hostname-from-ip-address-to.html) w.r.t. a configuration you have given.